# I want to make my house look/looks(?) more beautiful

Tags: word-usage

I'm a beginner, please someone give me a detailed answer on this one. I'm also a newbie to this site, sorry if this question is supposed to be placed at somewhere else (other tags).

So, here are the sentences:

I want to make my house look/looks more beautiful
I want to make my house to look more beautiful

I want you not to go there
I don't want you to go there

Which one is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

1) This is using [make](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make) in the sense **to cause something** requires either a noun, or a verb without **to**. For example,

> The photograph makes him **look** about 80

In your sentence, **look** is the infinitive, and **looks** is the present simple (3rd person). We want the infinitive, so it is:

> I want to make my house **look** more beautiful

2) If you negate a sentence with **be** in it, you just put **not** after the verb:

> The ball is red
>   The ball is **not** red.

For all other verbs, you put **do not** in front of the verb:

> I want a red ball
>   I **do not** want a red ball

The main verb in this sentence is **want**: the correct sentence is therefore

> I **don't** want you to go there

There are circumstances in which one might want to phrase the wanting in a positive way, for example to emphasize the wanting, but then would be more likely to say

> I **do** want you not to go there.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing work on your house, you might say

> I want to make my house *(to) look* beautiful.

After the work is completed, you would say

> My house looks beautiful.